# something goes wrong with my if statement

Tags: php, forms

this is where I have prob ... I want this shows me "You Are a Joke" when someone choose $r and shows "You Have My Respect" when someone choose $p but it keep print "You Have My Respect" either way !

```
<?php
$r = ("silver"."bronze"."cooper");
$p = ("gold"."platinium"."diamond");
if($r == 'silver'.' bronze'.'cooper'){
    echo "You Are a Joke";
} elseif ($p == "gold"."platinium"."diamond"){
    echo "You Have My Respect";
} else {
    echo "Your Rank Is *** Bro";
}
?>
```

Comment: You have an extra space in "bronze" in the condition. Do it like this: `if($r == 'silver'.'bronze'.'cooper') {`

Comment: now its just print you are a joke""

Comment: The logic in your example is wrong. You are checking if $r == "gold"."platinium"."diamond", which is always true because you're setting it to that value. The second condition is also always true, but as it's using an 'elseif' and the first condition is always true it never fires.

Either use the same variable to check the condition or introduce a third variable to hold the choice and test that.

Also "gold"."platinum"."diamond" is just the same thing as "goldplatinumdiamond" so I'm not entirely sure what you were after there either.

Answer (score 0):

remove `extra space` from `' bronze'` so it will solve your problem

```
 <?php
      $r = ("silver"."bronze"."cooper");
      $p = ("gold"."platinium"."diamond");
      if($r == 'silver'.'bronze'.'cooper'){ //remove extra space
         echo "You Are a Joke";
      } elseif ($p == "gold"."platinium"."diamond"){
         echo "You Have My Respect";
      } else {
         echo "Your Rank Is *** Bro";
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: I did but now it just keep printing "you are a joke"

Comment: bcoz your condition true first time so it will display first message every time

Comment: what could I do to prevent that?

Comment: but what you want to do